# Count number of rows for each ID within 1 year

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe something like this

```
Date        ID
01/01/2016  a
05/01/2016  a
10/05/2017  a
05/05/2014  b
07/09/2014  b
12/08/2017  b
```

What I need to do is to add a column which shows the number of entries for each ID that occurred within the last year and another column showing the number within the next year. I've written some horrible code that iterates through the whole dataframe (millions of lines) and does the computations but there must be a better way!

Comment: Within one year of the first date of each ID?

Comment: thanks for quick response - within 1 year of the date on each line, in other words it could be that person with ID a had 1 occurrence within a year of the date on line 2 but they had 0 in the year leading up to the event on line 3

Comment: just to add, the calculations need to show the number of occurrences within last/ next 365 days and not the previous/ next calendar year

Comment: @ARob4 - I edit answer, please check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filter first and then `groupby` and aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html).

Outputs are [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)ed and add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for add missing rows filled by `0`:

```
print (df)
         Date ID
0  01/01/2016  a
1  05/01/2016  a
2  10/05/2017  a
3  05/05/2018  b
4  07/09/2014  b
5  07/09/2014  c
6  12/08/2018  b
```

---

```
#convert to datetime (if first number is day, add parameter dayfirst)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
now = pd.datetime.today()
print (now)

oneyarbeforenow =  now - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)
oneyarafternow =  now + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)

#first filter
a = df[df['Date'].between(oneyarbeforenow, now)].groupby('ID').size()
b = df[df['Date'].between(now, oneyarafternow)].groupby('ID').size()
print (a)
ID
a    1
dtype: int64

print (b)
ID
b    2
dtype: int64

df1 = pd.concat([a,b],axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int).reindex(df['ID'].unique(),fill_value=0)
print (df1)
   0  1
a  1  0
b  0  2
c  0  0
```

EDIT:

If need compare each date by first date add or subtract [`year offset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects) per group need custom function with condition and `sum` Trues:

```
offs = pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)

f = lambda x: pd.Series([(x > x.iat[-1] - offs).sum(), \
                        (x < x.iat[-1] + offs).sum()], index=['last','next'])
df = df.groupby('ID')['Date'].apply(f).unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
  ID  last  next
0  a     1     3
1  b     3     2
2  c     1     1
```

Comment: thanks so much - this is very close to what i need. But rather than being based on *now* the counting needs to be based on the date in the first column. In other words I need to know the number of occurrences in the one year (365 days not calendar year) before/after the date in the Date column for each ID - sorry I wasn't clearer.

Comment: the last edit is perfect - thanks so much. anyone else using this code in future, check final edit. This code is also sufficiently fast.

Comment: Yes, exactly. thank you for accepting and nice weekend ;)

Comment: I believe you need [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) -  `df = df.join(df.groupby('ID')['Date'].apply(f).unstack(fill_value=0), 'ID')`

Answer (score 1):

```
In [19]: x['date'] = pd.to_datetime( x['date']) # convert string date to datetime pd object
In [20]: x['date'] = x['date'].dt.year # get year from the date

In [21]: x
Out[21]: 
   date id
0  2016  a
1  2016  a
2  2017  a
3  2014  b
4  2014  b
5  2017  b


In [27]: x.groupby(['date','id']).size() # group by both columns
Out[27]: 
date  id
2014  b     2
2016  a     2
2017  a     1
      b     1
```

Comment: thanks for this but it needs to be within the previous 365 days rather than the calender year

Answer (score 0):

Using `resample` takes care of missing inbetween years. See. year-2015

```
In [550]: df.set_index('Date').groupby('ID').resample('Y').size().unstack(fill_value=0)
Out[550]:
Date  2014-12-31  2015-12-31  2016-12-31  2017-12-31
ID
a              0           0           2           1
b              2           0           0           1
```

Use `rename` if you want only year in columns

```
In [551]: (df.set_index('Date').groupby('ID').resample('Y').size().unstack(fill_value=0)
             .rename(columns=lambda x: x.year))
Out[551]:
Date  2014  2015  2016  2017
ID
a        0     0     2     1
b        2     0     0     1
```