# Count number of rows for each ID within 1 year at each event date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df in the following format:

```
Date        ID    Score
01/01/2016  a    1
05/01/2016  a    2
10/05/2017  a    0
05/05/2014  b    3
07/09/2014  b    1
12/08/2017  b    2
```

The code [Count number of rows for each ID within 1 year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46095616/count-number-of-rows-for-each-id-within-1-year) was kindly answered and does nearly what I want. But I also need is a new column to show that for each ID and each date shows the number of events within the previous year before the date column, and another new column that shows the number of events within the next year following the date in the date column. I then need a further pair of columns that show the total score in a similar way as below:

```
ID    Date    Score    events_last_yr    events_next_yr    score_last_yr    score_next_yr
a    01/01/2016    1    0    2    0    2
a    05/01/2016    2    1    1    1    0
a    10/05/2016    0    2    0    3    0
b    05/05/2014    3    0    1    0    1
b    07/09/2014    1    1    1    3    0
b    12/08/2017    2    0    0    0    0
```

I've tried for ages using the code at the link above but not been able to adapt the code to do this. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What have you written so far?

Comment: thanks @Radan. I've tried the code at the link above (this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46095616/count-number-of-rows-for-each-id-within-1-year/46095982?noredirect=1#comment81473454_46095982). I'm fairly new to all this and somewhat out of my depth here!